# How to determine if a motor is spinning

Tags: motor

I am trying to figure out how much water is passing through a funnel, and to do so, I had the idea that I could set it up so the water will spin the shaft of a motor, which I have been led to believe will create a voltage that I can measure.

If this is even possible, which type of motor would I need, and how what sort of range will the voltage be in?

Comment: Related/dupe: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/11869/2028

Comment: Why not use a proper flow sensor? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_sensor http://www.newportus.com/ppt/images//h28p2.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term for this is dynamo (or generator), although it's the same most of the time. It depends on how much water will pass, what the pressure will be etc. what kind of dynamo you've to use. Perhaps you can use the dynamo of an old bicycle?

When the dynamo spins, an AC voltage will appear on the output. By rectifying and smoothing it you can get a smooth DC voltage (the same happens in almost every electronic device connected to AC power) which you can measure with a multimeter, microcontroller, IC, etc.

When you already have a motor, you can test if it works as a dynamo as well by connecting the + and - to a multimeter (has to be set to AC voltage). Make the motor spin very fast (really fast for some motors!) and check if there is an AC voltage. If so, it works as a dynamo. If not, it doesn't (or you have to spin faster)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it that way if you wanted a voltage output. Note that you will need to measure an AC signal in that case. Otherwise it is easier to use a device designed for the purpose. Most flow sensors are fairly expensive but [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/828) is pretty inexpensive and produces digital pulses corresponding to flow rate. It connects easily to 1/2" pipe, or can be used with adaptors to barbed fittings if you are using plastic tubing.

Comment: You can rectify an AC voltage as described in the second paragraph of my answer. After that, you have a DC voltage which you can measure with a multimeter, ADC, etc.